# Change range input value on radio button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a range input with radio buttons under it, i want when i click on each one of the radio buttons to increase the range input by 10 steps, and i don't want the user to be able to change the value when sliding i only want it to change on the click of the radio buttons, how can i do that? here is my code:

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
    width: 100%;
}

.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #4CAF50;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #4CAF50;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>

<input type="radio" name="radio-1">
<label>Change range</label>

<input type="radio" name="radio-2">
<label>Change range</label>

<input type="radio" name="radio-3">
<label>Change range</label>
```

Comment: What have you tried in regards to capturing the click of the radio buttons and making the change(s) you desire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For first question**, simple way is just disable #myrange, like `<input disabled>`.

**For second question**, just listen onchange/onclick event then adjust the value of #myrange.

**Like below demo:**

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}

function addRange() {
  let rangeValue = parseInt(slider.value)
  slider.value = rangeValue + 10
  
}

function addNamedRange(itemName) { 
  if(slider.attributes['data-ref-' + itemName]) { return } 
  slider.setAttribute('data-ref-' + itemName, true) 
  let rangeValue = parseInt(slider.value) 
  slider.value = rangeValue + 10 
}
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
    width: 100%;
}

.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #4CAF50;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #4CAF50;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange" disabled>
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>

<input type="radio" name="radio-1" onchange="addRange()">
<label>Change range</label>

<input type="radio" name="radio-2" onchange="addRange()">
<label>Change range</label>

<input type="radio" name="radio-3" onchange="addRange()">
<label>Change range</label>

<hr>

<p>
  <span style="font-weight:bold">Edit As OP requested:</span> 
  uses one data-ref of input[type=range] to store whehter radio box changed
</p>

<input type="radio" name="radio-progress" onchange="addNamedRange(this.name)">
<label>Change range</label>

<input type="radio" name="radio-progress" onchange="addNamedRange(this.name)">
<label>Change range</label>

<input type="radio" name="radio-progress" onchange="addNamedRange(this.name)">
<label>Change range</label>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your solution, but can you help me out in another thing? If those three inputs had the same name how can i make the value change once only when clicking on one of them please?

Comment: it sounds you need something like this: `function addRange(itemName) {
  if(slider.attributes['data-ref-' + itemName]) {
    return
  }
  slider.setAttribute('data-ref-' + itemName, true)
  let rangeValue = parseInt(slider.value)
  slider.value = rangeValue + 10
}`

Comment: can you update it in your answer please? because im getting errors

Answer (score 1):

Like this ?

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByName("radiobutton");
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

buttons[0].addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    slider.value = parseInt(slider.value) + 10;
    output.innerHTML = slider.value;
});

buttons[1].addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    slider.value = 50
    output.innerHTML = slider.value;
});

buttons[2].addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    slider.value = parseInt(slider.value) - 10
    output.innerHTML = slider.value;
});
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" disabled="true" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>

<input type="radio" name="radiobutton">
<label>add range</label>

<input type="radio" name="radiobutton">
<label>reset range</label>

<input type="radio" name="radiobutton">
<label>remove range</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Radio inputs should have same name, and added event listener for all.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}

document.querySelectorAll('[name="radio-1"]').forEach(input => {

  input.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    slider.value++;
    output.innerHTML = slider.value;
  });

});
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" disabled="true" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>

<input type="radio" name="radio-1">
<label>Change range</label>

<input type="radio" name="radio-1">
<label>Change range</label>

<input type="radio" name="radio-1">
<label>Change range</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Disable your slider so that user cannot change it.
- Give the same name to your radio.
- Add a jquery link to your code. (Added a CDN)
- I have added a jquery code to change range value on clicking a radio button.

```js
 <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
   
    var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
    var output = document.getElementById("demo");
    output.innerHTML = slider.value;

    slider.oninput = function () {
        output.innerHTML = this.value;
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
            slider.value = parseInt(slider.value) + 10;
            console.log(slider.value);
        });
    });
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
    width: 100%;
}

.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #4CAF50;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #4CAF50;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange" disabled>
    <p>Value:
        <span id="demo"></span>
    </p>
</div>

<input type="radio" name="radio">
<label>Change range</label>

<input type="radio" name="radio">
<label>Change range</label>

<input type="radio" name="radio">
<label>Change range</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go :)

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
}

$( '.change_range' ).each( function() {
  $(this).click( function( e ) {
    var el = $('#myRange');
    
    // set new ranges
    el.attr('min', $(this).data('range-from'));
    el.attr('max', $(this).data('range-to'));
    
    el.val( $(this).data('range-from') ); // reset to min
    slider.oninput(); // refresh
  } );
});
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
    width: 100%;
}

.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #4CAF50;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: #4CAF50;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="radioRange" class="change_range" data-range-from="10" data-range-to="20">
  Change range
</label>

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="radioRange" class="change_range" data-range-from="10" data-range-to="100">
  Change range
</label>

<label>
  <input type="radio" name="radioRange" class="change_range" data-range-from="2" data-range-to="12">
  Change range
</label>
```

Comment: To maintain the position of your slider (not fall back to `min`) you can calculate the current % like `percent = (old_max -old_min) /old_current` `new_current = ((max-min) *percent) + min`

Comment: fixed `label` and `input name` name aswell. a radio is ONE value, so the name is the same for all of them.